# Using VBA to Copy and Paste Columns to New sheet

Tags: excel, vba, format

I'm automating a few things for my job to try and create tables from data faster but we have to first take columns from our raw data and paste them to a new sheet as there is extraneous stuff that comes off the instrument. Currently I do it manually as shown below but I want to run a script that automatically pulls columns with: um2,mm2,#, measurement, or treatment in the header. These would be part of a string and the desired column titles would vary minus containing one of the things I just listed. I was thinking of using either InStr to automatically sort through and select the columns or just prompting userinput to select the appropriate ones. I prefer the automated if possible.

```
Sub CopyHeaders()
    Dim header As Range, headers As Range
    Set headers = Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:Z1")

    For Each header In headers
        If GetHeaderColumn(header.Value) > 0 Then
            Range(header.offset(1, 0), header.End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(2, GetHeaderColumn(header.Value))
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function GetHeaderColumn(header As String) As Integer
    Dim headers As Range
    Set headers = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:Z1")
    GetHeaderColumn = IIf(IsNumeric(Application.Match(header, headers, 0)), Application.Match(header, headers, 0), 0)
End Function
```

Was thinking of maybe using this to try and automate it but was unsure how to use the range I want.

```
Sub Test()
    Worksheets.FillAcrossSheets Sheet1.[A1:M1]
End Sub
```

I have attached an example of the headers, but the number of columns and titles will vary for each data set. Thanks!

[Header Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSMOp.png)

credit for above code:
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-to-merge-data-from-multiple-sheets-along-with-sheet-name.1171178/

Comment: That code from https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-to-merge-data-from-multiple-sheets-along-with-sheet-name.1171178/ seems to be for copy columns with known headers.  Have you tried to adapt it using your `Instr()` approach ?  PS when posting code from elsewhere it's useful to attribute it: if we thought you wrote that, we'd be wondering why you couldn't write one that works ;-)

Comment: Oops! will definitely edit the above to add credit, I use an index for credit in the overall code as it's much larger but forgot to add it back in for this. I did attempt the Instr() approach sort of  ```Sub FindString()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z1")
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If InStr(1, cell, "um2") > 0 Then
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = True
    Else
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = False
    End If
Next
End Sub```

Comment: I was hoping to either repeat this for each item listed above and then define it as a range I could use in the sub Test above but this approach would be clumsy and so far unviable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub CopyHeaders()
    Dim header As Range, headers As Range, ws As Worksheet, cDest As Range
    
    Set cDest = Worksheets("Copied data").Range("a1") 'first paste destination
    Set ws = Worksheets("Data")
    Set headers = ws.Range("A1:Z1").Cells
    
    For Each header In headers
        If Len(header.Value) > 0 Then
            If CopyThis(header.Value) Then
                ws.Range(header, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, header.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy _
                    cDest
                Set cDest = cDest.Offset(0, 1) 'move one column over
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

'copy this header and data?
Function CopyThis(hdr As String) As Boolean
    Dim v
    For Each v In Array("treatment", "measurement", "um2", "mm2", "#")
        If InStr(1, hdr, v, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            CopyThis = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next v
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to be appending data? If not, then this should work and it's pretty close to your code.

```
Sub CopyHeaders()
    Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsPaste As Worksheet
    Set wsData = Worksheets("Data")
    Set wsPaste = Worksheets("Raw Data")
    
    Dim header As Range, headers As Range
    Set headers = wsData.Range("A1:Z1")
    
    For Each header In headers.Cells
        If IsEmpty(header) Then
        
        'do nothing
        ElseIf testHeaderForMatch(header.Value) Then
            
            If GetHeaderColumn(header.Value) = 0 Then
                Dim lastColumn As Long
                lastColumn = wsPaste.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                wsPaste.Cells(1, lastColumn + 1).Value = header.Value
            End If
                
        wsData.Range(header.Offset(1, 0), header.End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=wsPaste.Cells(2, GetHeaderColumn(header.Value))
   
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function GetHeaderColumn(header As String) As Integer
    Dim headers As Range
    Set headers = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:Z1")
    GetHeaderColumn = IIf(IsNumeric(Application.Match(header, headers, 0)), Application.Match(header, headers, 0), 0)
End Function

Function testHeaderForMatch(theText As String) As Boolean
Dim theValidMembers As String
    theValidMembers = "um2, mm2, measurement,treatment"
Dim myTextArray() As String
    myTextArray = Split(theValidMembers, ",")

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(myTextArray) To UBound(myTextArray)
    If theText = myTextArray(i) Then
        testHeaderForMatch = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next i

End Function
```